# In Go, can you have function parameters with two distinct types?

Tags: go

Can you write a function in Go whose parameter can be two different types? For example, if I write a simple function that takes in an array/slice of `int` and simply returns the first value:

```
func First(array []int) int {
  return array[0]
}
```

Is there a way to type this such that we can also pass in a `[]string`, etc.? In TypeScript for example, we can do it like such without having to type the array as `any`:

```
const first = (array: (number | string)[]): number | string => {
  return array[0];
};
```

I've seen answers explaining the use of `interface{}` for situations like this... and maybe that's the only way, but it seems to close to `any` in TS and it feels like there might be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

(I haven't used Go for a few years, long before they introduced generics - so I'm basing my answer off [their documentation for generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics))

TypeScript's "generics" (in quotes) aren't really comparable to Go's generics. TypeScript is all about being able to *describe* an interface (in an abstract sense) for a runtime system built around type-erasure (i.e. JavaScript), while Go's is... <sub>honestly, **I have no idea**. I just don't know how Go's generics are implemented nor their runtime characteristics: [Articles on Go's generics](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3645228/go-language-adds-generics.html), [even from the language authors blog](https://go.dev/blog/why-generics) or [their own documentation site](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics) fail to mention key-terms like ***type erasure***, ***reified generics***, ***(template) instantiation*** or ***monomorph***, so if anyone has a better understanding please edit this post, or let me know in a comment!</sub>

Anyway, the good news is that as-of the Go 1.18 Beta, its support for generics includes support for generic constraints, but also support for *union types* as a constraint for generic type parameters (though I haven't yet found any information regarding support for other ADTs like *product types* and *intersection types*).

<sub>(Note that, at least for now, Go won't support union types as concrete types, but *in practice* that shouldn't be an issue)</sub>

---

In your case, if you want a function that returns the first element of a slice that could be either `[]int` or `[]string` (or returns some default-value if the slice is empty), then you can do this:

```golang
func First[T int | string](arr []T, ifEmpty T) T {
    for _, v := range arr {
        return v
    }

    return ifEmpty
}
```

While at first-glance you might think that this would allow for the `arr` slice to simultaneously contain both `int` and `string` values, this is not allowed (see below). Remember that generic parameters arguments are supplied by the caller and have to be valid concrete types, so `First` can only be *instantiated* as either `First[int]` or `First[string]`, which in-turn implies that `arr` can be *either* `[]int` *or* `[]string`.

Anyway, the full example below compiles and runs in the *Go dev branch* on [the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/4uhOSyxt1p-?v=gotip):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func First[T int | string](arr []T, ifEmpty T) T {
    for _, v := range arr {
        return v
    }

    return ifEmpty
}

func main() {

    // First[int]:
    arrayOfInts := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}

    firstInt := First(arrayOfInts, -1)
    fmt.Println(firstInt) // 2

    // First[string]:
    arrayOfStrings := []string{"life", "is short", "and love is always over", "in the morning"}
    
    firstString := First(arrayOfStrings, "empty")
    fmt.Println(firstString) // "life"

}
```

You can also extract the constraint `T int | string` and move it to an interface, and then use that as the constraint, which I personally think is easier to read, especially when you might need to repeat the same constraint in multiple places:

```golang
type IntOrString interface {
    int | string
}

func First[T IntOrString](arr []T, ifEmpty T) T {
    for _, v := range arr {
        return v
    }

    return ifEmpty
}
```

---

### Things you can't do...

Note that Go does not (currently, at least) allow using a `type` that describes a union as a variable's type *by itself* (nor can you use as a slice's element type either); you can only use a union as a constraint, otherwise you'll get the "interface contains type constraints" error. Which [means you can't describe an array](https://go.dev/play/p/T3GOleEyfqx?v=gotip) that can contain *both* `int` and `string` values *and* then use that interface for a concrete array type:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type IntOrString interface {
    int | string
}

func First[T IntOrString](arr []T, ifEmpty T) T {
    for _, v := range arr {
        return v
    }

    return ifEmpty
}

func main() {

    arrayOfIntsOrStrings := []IntOrString{2, "foo", 3, "bar", 5, "baz", 7, 11, 13} // ERROR: interface contains type constraints

    firstValue := First(arrayOfIntsOrStrings, -1)
    fmt.Println(firstValue)
}
```

> `./prog.go`:19:28: interface contains type constraints
> Go build failed.

---